# toggle specific divs that have two classes using checkboxes

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

ok so i have code that fundementally has this structure:

firstly a main div is openedand checkboxes are created using a foreach.  A checkbox is created for each 'model' in an array

```
<div id='coltext'>
  <input class ="ModelName1">
  <input class ="ModelName2">
```

etc.

following this another div is opened in a foreach loop under certain conditions:

```
  <div class="seqWrap">
    <div class="hit""ModelName1"></div>
    <div class="hit""ModelName2"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I the divs with the class hti, will be colored. I want to be able toggle the divs (class=hit), if the checkbox is checked/unchecked.  So if the checkbox "ModelName1" is checked, all divs that have a class="ModelName1" will have either a white background, or be hidden.

Can someone help with this?

Comment: I've rolled back your edit because you had changed the question so much that none of the answers made sense anymore. If you have a new question that different you should post it separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found your question a little confusing, but perhaps something like this is what you mean:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
   $('div.' + $(this).attr('class')).toggleClass('hit'); 
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cpXPX/

Note that your html has a typo in it for your child divs - you've got two double-quotes in the middle of the `class` attribute where you should have a space, so change:

```
<div class="hit""ModelName1"></div>
```

to

```
<div class="hit ModelName1"></div>
```

(As shown in my [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cpXPX/).)

Comment: i know u have already answered my uestion but now i ahve a new problem as a result, can u offer any help with this?

Comment: sorry i have the solution , just changled toggle class to toggle

Comment: This is very slow when i am using it,there are MANY divs involved,  is there a way fo making this faster that i could look into ?

Comment: I'm not sure: might need to see your real code to advise further. Though selecting by id is the fastest way, so you could try updating your child divs to have an `id="ModelName1"` instead of class and then change the input click handler to `$('#' + $(this).attr('class')).toggleClass('hit');` - I wouldn't expect it to make too much difference though.

Comment: Thanks , this  isn't working, but the whole process takes about 3/4 seconds to complete, this is quite slow for a toggle button , especially as there are up to ten of them ... ill repost a qs to optimise and link it here if u  could have a  look please

Answer (score 2):

I know you accept the answer you achieve this Pure CSS. Write like this:

```
.ModelName1:checked ~ .seqWrap .ModelName1,
.ModelName2:checked ~ .seqWrap .ModelName2
{background:none;}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/cpXPX/1/

Comment: +1 for bringing the `~` selector to my attention - it had somehow escaped my notice until now. But if another, say, ten checkboxes and related divs were added you'd have to add ten lines to the stylesheet wouldn't you? That's a bit more of a hassle to maintain...

Comment: this will not work for me as the example i gave was very basic to keep it simple, there can be more checkboxes, up to 10, and therre can be potentially 700 different names/title.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function(){
  if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    $('div.'+$(this).attr("class")).hide();
  else
    $('div.'+$(this).attr("class")).show();
})
```

Comment: i treid this and has not worked, this is how i thought it should be also, but its not working.  would  it be because I am using two classes for each div?

Comment: @user1338194 - your html as shown in the question has a mistake (see my answer). odiszapc - note that `this.checked` is both easier to read and more efficient than `$(this).is(':checked')`.